# How to choose and open a file during runtime with C++?

Tags: c++, textures, openfiledialog

At the moment I am creating an Editor for Textures and I want to choose the textures during runtime. Later I would like to choose the save directory for new textures.

I found the 
[How to: Open Files Using the OpenFileDialog Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61097ykx.aspx). But I think this is not the solution. 
[image: OpenFileDialog]

Comment: would you post some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Why do you think this is not a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with using the dirent.h file. I have acknowledge of this file by founding this post [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

I have write my own fileexplorer by using dirent.h and SFML.

Sorry if i can't illustrate my problem.

but thanks for the replies (:

Answer (score 0):

(assuming you are on Windows, pas per screenshot)
If you simply want to select a folder, you can use SHBrowseForFolder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

M.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the Common Dialog Library.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645524(v=vs.85).aspx

Or, if you are only interested in Vista/Windows 7 support, you could consider the Common Item Dialogs instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx

For 'native' C++ you wouldn't be able to easily use the .NET components that your link refers to.